# Having trouble with getting the debugger to work on a C program in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am getting this error:

```
Internal debugger error: unable to find executable for '/home/ubuntu/workspace/ffmpeg_pcm_f32le_encoder/build/f32le_transcode_mem '
```

However this file exists:

```
$ /home/ubuntu/workspace/ffmpeg_pcm_f32le_encoder/build/f32le_transcode_mem
Usage: /home/ubuntu/workspace/ffmpeg_pcm_f32le_encoder/build/f32le_transcode_mem <input file> <output file>
```

My launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/${fileBasenameNoExtension} ",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
  ]
}
```

Running this on Ubuntu 18.04

lldb version 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Of course, after asking the question, I immediately found the answer:

I had a space after the program name: 
`"${workspaceFolder}/build/${fileBasenameNoExtension} "`

It needs to be `"${workspaceFolder}/build/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"`

Answer (score 0):

This question has helped me while trying to debug C using VSCodium.
Thanks for asking it :)

For anyone here for the same reason I edited my launch.json as follows:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
```

When you want to debug a program just compile your code:

```
gcc program.c -o program
```

And use VSCodium's GUI to start debugging

Check out [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/vsCodium/comments/w9kaag/what_is_the_equivalent_of_the_ms_c_extension_with/) for more info about C support in VSCodium

Hope this helps ;)